# Is the Furnace EXP farm better than the Mob farm?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

##### Details

I am on **Minecraft : Bedrock Edition v1.17.41** I play on a world where the **Caves & Cliffs Experimental Mode** is on

##### Situation

I am in need of lots and lots of EXP, I need it for Enchanting purposes (as everyone does) I need to find a way to get alot of EXP fast, as I am a very impatient person and I want to get it the most cheapest way and the laziest way (preferably AFK farms).

The **Furnace EXP farm** only uses furnace and farmable items like bamboo and cactus.
The problem is I don't have them and it's hard to get those items.

The **Mob EXP farm** uses the killing of mobs and some automatic farms uses Trident which is hard to get, and the normal Mob farms requires me to NOT AFK.

I want to decide to which one of them works best, if none then please suggest a new one.

Comment: IIRC, bamboo furnace farm has changed after 1.17 update and doesn't totally work AFK. At least, the one I used.

Comment: Cheapest and laziest way would be to use commands

Comment: Tridents aren't that hard to get in bedrock edition. It's actually a very common drop compared to java edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that Mob XP farms are the most efficient, they yield more than furnaces.

If your problem are resources needed to build it, my suggestion will be **Endermen XP farm**. You can slay them easily with a diamond sword and get lots of XP in just one minute (and Ender Pearls as bonus).
It's not AFK though, but XP rate is really good.